# Creating a puppet package provider - "No command service defined for provider"

Tags: ruby, puppet, supervisord

I'm attempting to create a Service provider for [supervisord](http://www.supervisord.org).
I'm neither a Ruby programmer nor have I ever created one of these before, and the documentation is either terrible or difficult to find or not about the kind of Provider I'm trying to create.

The source for this provider is here:

[/lib/puppet/provider/service/supervisor/supervisor.rb](https://gist.github.com/4273546)

When I run the puppet agent, I get this error on the logstash service I've named "supervisor" as the provider for:

```
err: /Service[logstash]/ensure: change from false to running failed: No command service defined for provider
```

So, what am I doing wrong? Also, if you find anything else funky in that provider, let me know!

Also, if you know any documentation/blog posts/whatever that actually describe the interface and how to create one of these things properly, please share. I've had trouble finding much of anything related to creating providers at all, let alone Service providers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the references to `command(:service)`, e.g.

```
def startcmd
  [command(:service), "start", @resource[:name]]
end
```

This looks for a pre-defined command in the provider called "service", hence the error.  You've got two defined commands:

```
commands :supervisord => "/usr/bin/supervisord",
         :supervisorctl => "/usr/bin/supervisorctl"
```

So your references in restartcmd, startcmd and stopcmd should change to `command(:supervisorctl)` - assuming that's the command that'll let you start/stop.

The `commands` line at the top will cause Puppet to only use the provider if those are all available on the host.  The `command(:name)` call is then getting the full path to them and you're returning the full command and arguments for the `base` service provider to run when it starts/stops/restarts the service.

The docs don't go into much detail on the helpers methods like `commands` that you're coming across here.  I would suggest reading both the [custom types](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/custom_types.html) and [providers](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/provider_development.html) pages, plus Richard Crowley's [Extending Puppet slides](http://rcrowley.org/talks/sv-puppet-2011-01-11/).  There's also a book due out at the end of 2012 from two Puppet Labs employees: [Puppet Types and Providers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449339328).

What you're also running into is that your provider is extending the `base` service provider - which is the right thing to do, but it expects derivatives to work in particular ways (e.g. the *cmd methods).  New types and providers can be simpler.

Comment: I'm almost entirely sure this is what's causing it. I hadn't even noticed that was still in there. I was using another provider as the foundation, so I must have left that piece in by accident. Thanks! It looks like I should change it to command(:supervisorctl), then.